# Unable to change NVIDIA GeForce fans

Tags: drivers, nvidia, vnc, fan

I am running a remote Ubuntu system. I have ssh access and VNC desktop access with xfce4.
When running my GPU the fans only go up to about 60% and it's running about 85°C.
I understand that you can only change fan speed via the nvidia-settings GUI, but via the VNC Desktop I only have these 2 options:

[image]

I have tried changing

```
> 
cd /./etc/X11/
sudo -s [because you need root access]
gedit Xwrapper.config &
add the line needs_root_rights=yes before allowed_users=console.
Reboot your machine
Therefore the Xwrapper.config file will be:
```

The terminal window says:

```
MESSAGE: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort  
Message: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

My drivers seem to be working. nvidia-smi works fine and it can handle some mining that I did as a benchmark.

Comment: try `nvidia-settings -c 0` or `nvidia-settings -c :0`.  I'm not sure that will work as I have not attempted it, I'm guessing `$DISPLAY` is set to 1 in VNC which isn't using the GPU.

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu release details; and if using a LTS release which kernel stack you're using (*this can impact drivers given they are kernel modules*)